# can we an external table in Trino with an external location in Amazon S3 or Azure blob storage using dataproc metastore

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, trino, google-cloud-dataproc-metastore

Had set up trino cluster in GKE, using hive connector with dataproc metastore service to create external tables with external location in GCS cloud storage. But when I tried to create external tables in Azure Blob Storage with an external location, I got the following error in the dataproc metastore service:
Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException No FileSystem for the "s3" scheme.